# Model validation does not work in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using MVC3 and added model validation with required attributes. Then I have created page which has jquery dialog (not ajax dialog). Validation does not work in that case. But if I put html from dialog to page it works fine.

Does any body know how to solve problem?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $("#registerDialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, show: "blind", hide: "explode", modal: true, resizable: false, height: 570, width: 390 });

  $(".headerButton").button(); 
  $(".accountBtn").button(); 
  $('ul').roundabout({ autoplay: 'false', autoplayDuration: 3000 }); 

  $("#registerBtn").click(function () { 
    $("#registerDialog").dialog("open"); return false; }); 
    $("#closeRegisterDialog").click(function () { $("#registerDialog").dialog("close"); 
   }); 

   $("#registerBtnSbmt").click(function () {
     $("#registerForm").submit(); return false; }); 
   })



@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerForm" }))
{       

    <div id="registerDialog" title="Регистрация">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "registerUser" })
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)          
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "registerUser" })            
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)          
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "registerUser" })           
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)           
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "registerUser" })           
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)          
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "registerUser" })            
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)                                   
        <br/>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.RememberYou) запомнить Вас?                        
        <br/>
         <br/>
        @Html.ActionLink("Сохранить", "LogIn", "Account", null, new { @class = "accountBtn", style = "font-size: 0.8em;", id = "registerBtnSbmt" })
       <a href="#" class="accountBtn" id="closeRegisterDialog" style = "font-size: 0.8em;">Закрыть</a>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you use to generate the dialog

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#registerDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 570,
        width: 390
    });

Comment: $(".headerButton").button();
    $(".accountBtn").button();
    $('ul').roundabout({ autoplay: 'false', autoplayDuration: 3000 });

    $("#registerBtn").click(function () {
        $("#registerDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    $("#closeRegisterDialog").click(function () {
        $("#registerDialog").dialog("close");
    });

    $("#registerBtnSbmt").click(function () {      
        $("#registerForm").submit();
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: Hm... How to format the code?:)

Comment: Can you post the html from registerDialog?

Comment: From Heinz-Josef Lücking (not enough rep to comment here) : When does your custom code get included? I had a fault where i included my custom code befor the jquery script files. It worked when i included them after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your form tags inside of your dialog. You will notice when you create the dialog and open it, it moves your div out of your form. You would want:

```
<div id="registerDialog" title="Регистрация">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerForm" }))
    {       

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "registerUser" })
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)          
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "registerUser" })            
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)          
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "registerUser" })           
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)           
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "registerUser" })           
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)          
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)           
        <br/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "registerUser" })            
        <br/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)                                   
        <br/>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.RememberYou) запомнить Вас?                        
        <br/>
         <br/>
        @Html.ActionLink("Сохранить", "LogIn", "Account", null, new { @class = "accountBtn", style = "font-size: 0.8em;", id = "registerBtnSbmt" })
       <a href="#" class="accountBtn" id="closeRegisterDialog" style = "font-size: 0.8em;">Закрыть</a>
    }
</div>
```

There is an explanation of why this happens at the bottom of this [page](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4458)

From the page:

> One of the requirements of the dialog is that it appear as the
>   top-most element. The only way to accomplish this consistently in
>   Internet Explorer is to have the dialog be the last element in the
>   body, as it respects DOM order over z-index. There are generally two
>   work-arounds:
>
> ```
> move the dialog element back somewhere else in the dom in the open event callback. This has the potential to allow other elements to
> ```
>
> appear on top of the dialog (see above)
>
> ```
> move the dialog content element somewhere else in the dom in the close event callback, before the submit.
> ```
>
> Neither of these are suitable for building in to the dialog, and are
>   left as suggested work-arounds. As the first comment on this ticket
>   suggests, this needs to be documented better.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot xbrady!!!!!! I spent more than 2 hours to solve that problem. I have to be more attentive.

Comment: Up at the top left my my answer there is an up arrow, 0 and a down arrow. Click the up arrow and click the check mark below the down arrow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly sorry for not answered before, so, go to the answer.

1. In a modal windows, not is possible, this not work, cause is necessary refresh the page, so...
2. To solved the problem, use the attribute [required], and change the title for replace the messagem default.
   Note: Admitting that you gotta knowledge about create a modal window let's go the code: (I'm use ASP.NET MVC 5, it's works for HTML 5x, to old version nope)

[image]

That's result:

[image]